# OnClick event - check which is the sender

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to call one event every time when something on my page is clicked (whether a control or something else), and then in that function to check which is the sender?

Comment: Can you explain bit more clear?

Comment: Every click is an event that can be identified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

like this?

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

This will capture all clicks in the document and log the node on which the event started. It's a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but without understanding the problem it's the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('*').click(function(){
        var $sender = $(window.event.target);
    });
});
```

However, you'll have all sorts of propegation issues I'd imagine, plus I dont know if all dom elements respond to the `.click()` event.

It'd be better to tag all the items you want to be clickable with a class name, so it becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $('.clickable').click(function(){
        var $sender = $(window.event.target);
    });
});
```

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify which item being clicked like this. The below script will take care of all a tag in your page.

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
    // e.preventDefault(); prevent default behaviour if needed
     alert("Invoked from "+$(this).attr("id"));   
    });
});​
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/yBfUq/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed, although I cannot think of any reason you would want to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/WkNPg/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body *").click(function(event){
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    })        

});
```

This will alert the id, but you can make it so anything you want based on the "sender".

Comment: this is going to bind the event handler to _every element_ instead of allowing the event to bubble up.