# JQuery not adding class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I'm struggeling with some code, I have code to when I click a `<p>` element it changes the iframe src and removes the class 'active' of all the elements in the .html file and then add the class 'active' to the clicked element.

But the class 'active' never gets added to the clicked element.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function loadIframe(url){
    $('.iframe_settings').attr('src', url);
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
};
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="w-100" id="http://whatever.com/" onclick="return loadIframe(this.id);">
    <p>

        <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="nav-label">Intranet</span>

    </p>
</li>
```

Comment: Check what is `this` and you'll get the answer why...

Comment: provide class or id insteed of 'this', what is this in this code?

Comment: this is nothing in context you are using it. holding url in id? onclick handlers with functions might cause problems, use event binding instead.

Comment: pass another parameter as `this` in function and use it for add/remove class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could pass the context (element) to the handler. I expect this to work:

```
loadIframe(this.id, this)
```

And,

```
function loadIframe(url, element){
    $('.iframe_settings').attr('src', url);
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(element).addClass('active');
};
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Stray comment: I am not sure if it is a good practice to call url an id. You might find data-attributes useful. Attributes like `data-id = ""`. In fact I would call it `data-url`.

Comment: How would I then pass that through?
Like loadIframe(this.data-url, this); ??

Comment: I found out myself :D For anyone wondering I did this: this.getAttribute('data-url')

Comment: There is a neat way in `jquery` to do this (imo). I think it is called `$.data('url')` if your data-attribute is called `data-url`. Here is a link: https://api.jquery.com/data/.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `$(this).addClass();`

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287759/getting-sender-in-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298629/onclick-event-check-which-is-the-sender)

Comment: ouch, 82Tuskers was faster ;)

Comment: It would have been better if you could provide the answer directly instead of redirecting them to a different question. This can save a lot of searching for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your code add identifier in correct way.

```
function loadIframe(url){
    $('.iframe_settings').attr('src', url);
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $("#"+url).addClass('active');
};
```